# Google Play update failure

Tags: android, google-play, android-update-app

I had an android app that I developed a couple of years ago (version 6) and I have just updated it several times this week and changed everything completely (now version 12). I have just realized that the update is not really effective on google play. I mean those who still have the old version (version 6), when they check on google play, it shows as if their old version is up to date and it never updates. However, those who have relatively new versions, say version 11, are able to update to version 12 and so on. Something weird happened between version 6 and 7 which I don't get? Can someone help.

FYI: I made sure to sign it with the same keystore and keep the same package name as recommended. I also updated the version name and code on Gradle and Manifest files.

Comment: Did you change the target SDK version? Devices with an older Android will then not get the update.

Comment: I left it as default (23). Could that be the problem? If yes, what should I change it to?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: I changed minSdkVersion from 8 to 14. But does this mean that devices with an sdk of 20 would still fail to update, because this was actually the case?

Comment: No, devices with sdk version 20 should not be affected by this change.